# php set_error_handler not working properly

Tags: php, error-handling

I defined handler function in `functions.php`:

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    echo "An error: $errstr";
    return true; // Preventing standard handler
}
```

Then I used it in `set_error_handler`:

```
require_once('functions.php');
set_error_handler("errorHandler");
```

But when I trigger notice, I get standard PHP message: `Notice: Undefined variable: thisVariableDoesntExist in...`, `set_error_handler` doesn't handle `E_ERROR`, but here I have notice, so I can't get it why this doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked as expected.

Comment: maybe the problem is that I used it in Opencart, index file

Comment: I'm not sure why that would make a difference. It's possible Opencart does `restore_error_handler()`, but I can't see any way that it would know that you called `set_error_handler()` and it needed to revert it.

Comment: I found some `restore_error_handler()`, but they are all in extensions' files and shouldn't affect handler in index file, that's weird

Comment: IIUC, `set_error_handler()` and `restore_error_handler()` implement a stack. I'd expect those extensions to just be undoing their own `set_error_handler()`, so it should go back to your handler, not the default. I'm not sure why it's not working for you.